# Updating dynamically determined fields with peewee

Tags: python, mysql, peewee

I have a peewee model like the following:

```
class Parrot(Model):
    is_alive = BooleanField()
    bought = DateField()
    color = CharField()
    name = CharField()
    id = IntegerField()
```

I get this data from the user and look for the corresponding id in the (MySQL) database. What I want to do now is to update those attributes which are not set/empty at the moment. For example, if the new data has the following attributes:

```
is_alive = True
bought = '1965-03-14'
color = None
name = 'norwegian'
id = 17
```

and the data from the database has:

```
is_alive = False
bought = None
color = 'blue'
name = ''
id = 17
```

I would like to update the bought date and the name (which are not set or empty), but without changing the is_alive status. In this case, I could get the new and old data in separate class instances, manually create a list of attributes and compare them one for one, updating where necessary, and finally saving the result to the database. However, I feel there might be a better way for handling this, which could also be used for any class with any attributes. Is there?

Answer (score 0):

**MySQL** Solution:

```
UPDATE my_table SET  
    bought = ( case when bought is NULL OR bought = '' ) then ? end )
  , name   = ( case when name   is NULL OR name   = '' ) then ? end )
  -- include other field values if any, here
WHERE
  id = ?
```

Use your scripting language to set the parameter values.
In case of the parameters matching the old values, then update will not be performed, by default.

Comment: Thanks. But wouldn't the is_alive parameter from my example be replaced with the new one in this case?

Comment: Unless you set a specific field for updation, it wont change in the table.

Comment: So I still need to get the DB entry first to determine whether, say, is_alive should be updated? Then I can do a general _update_ as mentioned at the end of the question, and do not need to select any fields at MySQL level...

Comment: As you already have old and instances of data in hand, you can check if `is_alive` needs any update. If yes, set the same in the `update` statement as suggested in my answer.